# Schema only restore to new postgreSQL DB with a text format dump

Tags: postgresql, schema, restore

```
psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.3.5
```

I am trying to restore only the schema. I have tried the following command:

```
pg_restore -s -d rh /path/to/dump.sql
pg_restore: [archiver] input file appears to be a text format dump. Please use psql.
```

I have tried looking in the documentation of psql and have not found a schema-only flag.

If you know of any other technique to acheieve this I would be very appreciative.

If it helps I am using OSX Version 10.10

Comment: That's the problem with the "plain text" dumps. The "schema only" option is only possible if you create a "custom" dump using `pg_dump -Fc`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can generate a text dumpfile using -s to generate only schema dump like this :

```
pg_dump -s <database name> > pg_dump_text_filename
```

You should use psql command to connect to your database :

```
psql -U <username> -d <databasename>
```

and then at the psql prompt use this :

```
\i <pg_dump_text_file_path>
```

You can also use the archive file format of pg_dump :

```
pg_dump -Fc -f <archive file> <database name>
```

And then pg_restore only the schema :

```
pg_restore -d <database name> -s <archive file>
```

Comment: Will this do schema only and not the data?

Comment: I edited my post with pg_dump option to exclude data.